# .htaccess protect directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to protect all directories with one .htpasswd but the **/private** directory with a different one.

this is my htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted"
AuthUserFile /home/www/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

The problem with this approach is that all directories require the same password. I need to specify a different one only for the **/private** directory. Is it possible to achieve this using only one .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using the `<FilesMatch>` directive. So if the file matches `private.html` then it will use this different authentication.

```
<FilesMatch "private.html">
AuthName "Member Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/username/.htpasswd
require user admin
</FilesMatch>
```

You will also notice that I've used `require user admin` instead of `require valid-user`. I've done this because it then limits it to only the person(s) that know the logins to the user admin to access the `/private/` directory.

Just change `admin` to what ever username you'd like to use for the authentication.